# How to get the key in an array when the value is known and the keys are strings of numbers?

Tags: php, arrays

There seems to be a bug with array_search, how do I work around it?

```
$arr = [
    "0" => "Zero",
    "1" => "One",
    "2" => "Two",
];

$val = array_search("Zero", $arr, true);

echo gettype($val); // returns integer instead of string
echo $val;
```

I want to get "0" instead of 0. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Hint: `var_dump($arr);`. That's how PHP arrays work by spec: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.key-casts

Comment: An index is an integer, why would you expect a string?

Comment: So the problem is in the declaration of the array

Comment: Because an index like "example" works fine, why would "0" not?

Comment: Because numbers represent associative arrays, `$arr['example']` is not associative so this works fine. You're trying to use numbers, thus they will always be integers in an assoc array.  Why don't you [typecast](https://3v4l.org/hL2QT) if its that important? `$val = (string) array_search("Zero", $arr, true);`

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks guys.

Comment: There isn't any problem, it's how it works. Explanation about integer keys from my previous link "Strings containing valid decimal ints, unless the number is preceded by a + sign, will be cast to the int type. E.g. the key "8" will actually be stored under 8. On the other hand "08" will not be cast, as it isn't a valid decimal integer."

Answer (score 0):

You can typecast if needs a string result:

```php
    $arr = [
        "0" => "Zero",
        "1" => "One",
        "2" => "Two",
    ];
    
    $val = (string) array_search("Zero", $arr, true);// You can typecast to String here
    
    echo gettype($val); // this will return string now
    echo $val;
```